# Как оформить цикл на ассемблере?

Tags: c, ассемблер

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1251");
    int n;
    int a;
    int b = 0;
    cout << "Введите число, с которым будем работать" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        _asm
        {
            MOV EAX, b 
            MOV EBX, 10
            MUL EBX // результат хранится в EDX:EAX (b*10)
            MOV EDX, 0
            MOV ECX, EAX
            MOV EAX, n
            DIV EBX // в EDX теперь остаток
            ADD ECX, EDX
            MOV b, ECX
        }
        n = n / 10;
    }
    cout << b << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: так а вопрос какой?

Answer (score 0):

```
MOV ECX, кол-во итераций
метка:
.....
loop метка
```

Если не знаете заранее сколько итераций, то тогда использовать джампы

```
метка:
......
jnz метка
```

jnz - переход, если ZF = 0

Answer (score 0):

```
    mov eax, n
    xor edx, edx
    mov ebx, 10
    ;начало цикла
loop:
    test eax, eax
    jz endl
    ;тело цикла
    div ebx
    jmp loop
endl:
    ;конец
```

Если в теле цикла используются эти же регистры, то можно сделать так:

```
push eax
;тело цикла
pop eax
mov ebx, 10
xor edx, edx
```

Так же есть [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) для таких целей.